iTerm2 + Starship + zsh-autosuggestions
I'm on a mac.
This erroneous behaviour only occurs in iTerm2. Not in the built in Terminal application. Not in Warp.
If I activate the Starship prompt. Combined with if I activate the zsh-autosuggestions plugin in my .zshrc. I get this error.
Even if it's the default prompt, with no changes in Starship.toml.
When I type the start of a command, the cursor at some point, usually after a few characters, jumps a few positions to the right. Leaving a trail to the left of part of the characters I just typed. And after this happens, I can no longer backspace all the way to the start of the original prompt. Instead it's like the start of the prompt is after the part of the command that I typed before the auto suggestions kicked in.
Here's another example with another comand:


I use iTerm2, Starship, and zsh-autosuggestions at the same time but haven't encountered this issue. You might be able to refer to my configuration https://github.com/tshu-w/dotfiles/tree/main/config and bisect the minimum configuration to identify the problem.

Best to ask this on [apple.se]. Off-topic here...
